# Basic threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

i am completley new to threading.

Basically i am querying many databases and have made a custom loading form to indicate the data is loading. However this locks up(my loading form page) when running the same time as my database code. What do i need to research in order to complete this functionality ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: I'll give you a thumbs up anyway.  :)

Answer (score 1):

There is special component for running long tasks in background - [**BackgroundWorker**](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).